# OpenCV how to use drawn on line as a reference point

Tags: opencv, ros

I am creating a lane detection algorithm, I am struggling to find out how to measure the curve of the road, so I have drawn a line at the center of the lane, in which i want my ROS bot to follow, I have found a method to make the ROS bot follow a drawn on line, however I am struggling to make it follow the line drawn by open cv when it detects lanes.

Currently the ROS bot will only follow the lanes on top of the line and not in the middle of the lane

[The lane](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nzf3k.png)

The bot will currently follow the yellow line, however that isnt how a car should drive, as it should be in the middle of the lane. So during my lane detection I drew 3 lines like this.

[Lane Detection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M82f3.png)

The green line however isnt a physical line and is drawn from opencv, so i am struggling to make the bot follow the green line drawn.

Comment: Could you post a picture or something to clear up your question?

Comment: look at how ROS makes the bot "follow" lines. now you do the same, by giving it the information that ROS would otherwise calculate from a center line. you "just" have to find the left and right side markings (tricky) and calculate appropriate coordinates. -- this dovetails into a research question. how to detect lanes? generally not trivial. successful users use AI.

Comment: Are you feeding the updated image/frame with the "green" line to the bot at every timestamp?

Comment: yes, the green line is updated 10 times every frame

Comment: What logic is the bot using to follow the "yellow" line currently? Can you use the same logic to follow the "green" one?

Comment: The way the bot follows the yellow line currently is it finds the center point of the yellow line using centroid detection, then goes straight if the bot is in the center and then left/right if the center is left of right. However since the yellow line is a real thing and not drawn on, it is easy to communicate it to the bot. I am not sure how I can do that for the green line. I could try and use the coordinates that I get from the green line